# How to know which element is in focus in Universal windows application in windows 10

Tags: c#-4.0, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a xaml page in universal windows application in windows 10. This page contains two listboxes. Both listboxes have the same ItemsSource like

```
public class CategoryModel
{
 public int CategoryId {get; set;}
 public string CategoryName {get; set;}
 public List<string> ImageURL {get; set;}
}
```

The top listbox creates Menu header at the top in Horizontal manner and the bottom listbox creates Menu data at the bottom of the menu header in Vertical manner.

The problem is that how to know which menu data element at the bottom is in focus, so that I can highlight the same element in Menu header?

```
                    <ListView x:Name="lvMenuBar" Grid.Column="1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCategories}" Width="Auto">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Click="MenuBarClick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Tag="{Binding CategoryId}" Content="{Binding CategoryName}" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="18" Margin="0" Padding="20" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0" Opacity="0.5" Foreground="Black"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    </ListView>

                    <ListView x:Name="lvMenuBar" Grid.Column="1" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCategories}" Width="Auto">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
```

The above is my XAML

Comment: Could you share your XAML?

Comment: I don't really get, what you need to know, sorry. Do you want to know, which element in the bottom ListBox is selected, sothat you can highlight the same element at the top ListBox?

Comment: Yes @einRobby. I want to highlight the top depending upon the menu element at the bottom

Comment: @RareNCool I have edited the post with XAML

Comment: Is your XAML complete? This looks like one-and-a-half `ListView` -- and they both have the same name...?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to select (or otherwise highlight) an item in the top list whenever that item is selected in the bottom list. You can do this with data binding, e.g.:

```
<ListView
    Grid.Row="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCategories}"
    Margin="8"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=verticalList, Mode=OneWay}"
    >
```

Here the `SelectedIndex` property of the top list mirrors that of the bottom list.

In context, something like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView
        Grid.Row="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCategories}"
        Margin="8"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=verticalList, Mode=OneWay}"
        >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CategoryModel">
                <Button
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Tag="{Binding CategoryId}"
                    Content="{Binding CategoryName}"
                    Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}"
                    FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                    FontWeight="SemiBold"
                    FontSize="18"
                    Margin="0"
                    Padding="20"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Opacity="0.5"
                    Foreground="Black"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
    <ListView
        x:Name="verticalList"
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCategories}"
        Margin="8"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CategoryModel">
                <Button
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Tag="{Binding CategoryId}"
                    Content="{Binding CategoryName}"
                    Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}"
                    FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                    FontWeight="SemiBold"
                    FontSize="18"
                    Margin="0"
                    Padding="20"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Opacity="0.5"
                    Foreground="Black"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Caveat: When you click one of your buttons, the `ListView` doesn't see that click; if you want that click to select an item, do it in code-behind.

Note also the `IsItemClickEnabled` property on the second (vertical) list.

---

EDIT: If I understand you correctly, you want the selection in the upper horizontal list to track scrolling in the lower vertical instead of selection. In that case you need to get hold of the built-in `ScrollViewer` and do something like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Loaded += (sender, args) =>
        {
            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(verticalList);
            if (scrollViewer != null)
            {
                scrollViewer.ViewChanged += (o, eventArgs) =>
                    {
                        int length = MenuCategories.Length;
                        double offset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
                        double height = scrollViewer.ExtentHeight;
                        int index = (int)(length * offset / height);
                        horizontalList.SelectedIndex = index;
                    };
            }
        };
}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (parent != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            T candidate = child as T;
            if (candidate != null)
            {
                return candidate;
            }

            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
            {
                return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

You'll probably need to experiment with the calculations here; this is a bit experimental on my part.

Comment: ...and if you want the lower list to mirror the upper list as well, just change the binding mode to `TwoWay`. :-)

Comment: I'd like to clarify this answer. The idea is that you have a collection of items and an integer in your DataContext(the source of your bindings) and two ListViews in your XAML. You bind the collection to the ListViews and the integer to the `SelectedItem` using `Mode = TwoWay` for both collections. This way when an item is selected from any of the two ListViews, the value of the integer changes and the other ListView is notified automatically.

Comment: You can certainly bind the `SelectedIndex` to a property, but that's not necessary for the bindings to work.

`SelectedItem` is an item reference; `SelectedIndex` is an index. Both can be used to synchronize the lists, and you only need a `TwoWay` binding on one of them to achieve that.

Comment: I meant `SelectedIndex` , not `SelectedItem` my mistake.

Comment: The above part does not work for me as I am just scrolling in the bottom listview. So, while scrolling the selected item or selected index does not change for the bottom listview.

Comment: I don't understand -- scrolling and item selection are different things.

Comment: The above solution works if you click within the listview but just on scrolling it is not working.

Comment: Yes @PetterHesselberg. On scrolling, the selected index of the vertical listview is not changing and it is not even triggering selectedindex change event.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you'd expect the selection to change because you are scrolling?

Comment: @PetterHesselberg I want to focus on the item on horizontal listview i.e. showing on surface tablet screen in vertical listview.

Comment: Do you mean you want to scroll selected items into view?

Comment: Suppose we have 10 items in the list. At the start of the page, I am on the first item. So I start scrolling from the first item and goes to fifth item due to speed of my scrolling. Now, how I will know I am on which element?

Comment: You can scroll the selected item out of view, of course. When you say "goes to the fifth item", do you mean that the fifth item shows on top of the list? I really don't understand what you're asking; scrolling is orthogonal to selection.

Comment: I want to know, which element is on screen of vertical listview depending upon that I can highlight the same element of horizontal listview.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a way (I hope) to track scrolling in the vertical list. If this doesn't help, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code has solved much of my issue

```
    private double _scrollExtentHeight;
    private ScrollViewer _scrollViewer; 

_scrollViewer = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(lvMenuItems);
        if (_scrollViewer != null)
        {
            _scrollViewer.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
            _scrollViewer.DirectManipulationCompleted += scrollViewerDirectManipulationCompleted;
            _scrollExtentHeight = _scrollViewer.ExtentHeight;
        }



    private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent)
where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parent != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                T candidate = child as T;
                if (candidate != null)
                {
                    return candidate;
                }

                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                {
                    return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    private void scrollViewerDirectManipulationCompleted(object sender, object e)
    {
        _menuVM.StartDispatcher();
        if (_scrollViewer != null)
        {
            int length = _menuVM.Categories.Count;
            double offset = _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
    //Horizontal scroll viewer
            List<Button> menuItems = GetAllMenuItemControl(lvMenuBar); 
            int currIndex = 0, index = 0;
    //Categories height ratio contains the height ratio of each element for total height
            for (; index < _menuVM.CategoriesHeightRatio.Count; index++)
            {
                if ((_menuVM.CategoriesHeightRatio[index - 1 > 0 ? index - 1 : 0] * _scrollExtentHeight) < offset && (_menuVM.CategoriesHeightRatio[index] * _scrollExtentHeight) >= offset)
                {
                    currIndex = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    menuItems[index].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    menuItems[index].Opacity = 0.5;
                }
            }
            menuItems[currIndex].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 2);
            menuItems[currIndex].Opacity = 1;
            var transform = lvMenuBar.TransformToVisual(menuItems[currIndex]);
            Point absolutePoint = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
            svMenuBar.ChangeView(Math.Abs(absolutePoint.X), null, null, false);
        }
    }

    private List<Button> GetAllMenuItemControl(DependencyObject parent)
    {
        var _List = new List<Button>();
        for (int index = 0; index < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); index++)
        {
            var _Child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, index);
            if (_Child is Button)
                _List.Add(_Child as Button);
            _List.AddRange(GetAllMenuItemControl(_Child));
        }
        return _List;
    }
```